# What am I doing wrong with my code to change css properties?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm overriding the css for the listviews in my jquerymobile project with the following css

```
li{
height:90px !important;
border-style: 0px !important;
border-width: 0px 5px 2px 0px !important;
-moz-border-image: url('images/FA-iPhone_my-goals_READY-(2)_02.png') 0 5 2 0 stretch     !important;
-webkit-border-image: url('images/FA-iPhone_my-goals_READY-(2)_02.png') 0 5 2 0 stretch     !important;
-o-border-image: url('images/FA-iPhone_my-goals_READY-(2)_02.png') 0 5 2 0 stretch     !important;
border-image: url('images/FA-iPhone_my-goals_READY-(2)_02.png') 0 5 2 0 fill stretch !important;}
```

That works. However, Within each listview, I have an image which i am using as a button. I wrapped the image with a div and gave that div the id of "#selectbtn". I'm trying to use the method here:

http://www.jquery4u.com/dynamic-css-2/change-css-jquery/

So with this code below, `#four1` is the id of the page (jquerymobile considers it a page)
`#selectbtn` of course is the name of the image that's used as a button within the listview. The image has text that says "select". So I'm hoping when I click it, it can change the properties and values for the li selector above to the new properties and values below.

```
<script>
$('#four1').live('pagecreate', function(e){
$("#selectbtn").click(function(e) {
$('li').css({'height': '90px !important'});
$('li').css({'border-style': '0px !important'});
$('li').css({'border-width': '0px 5px 2px 0px !important'});
$('li').css({'-moz-border-image':url('+images/goalsel_02.png+ !important')'});
$('li').css({'-webkit-border-image':url('+images/goalsel_02.png+ !important')'});
$('li').css({'-o-border-image':url('+images/goalsel_02.png+')' !important});
$('li').css({'border-image': 'url('+images/goalsel_02.png+')' !important});

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: +1 For good example of abuse of `css` method in order to write very low quality code. You should use `addClass` in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign in JSON format, example:

```
$(element).css({ "property1" : "value1", "property2" : "value2" });
```

Or if you want to add just one property, use this:

```
$(element).css("property", "value");
```

Not the JSON format for the single property.

Comment: We both posted at the same time! LoL!

Comment: nah you have same code. you cloned it. Not everybody think like same. Maybe idea could be same but not answers.

Answer (score 1):

You should correctly assign properties.

```
$(element).css("property", "value"); //if assigning one property
```

or

```
$(element).css({ "property1" : "value1", "property2" : "value2" }); // more than 1 property and also keep that quotes right
```

You also have to care about your quotes.

Like

`$(element).css({ "background-image" : "url('path_to_image') !important" });`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers, do not select your element more than once. You could add all the css styles in one css function as shown by the answers.

If you want to apply other functions to given element, you could using chaining (see also: http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/quick-guide-chaining-in-jquery/). The reason behind this is that you don't want jQUery to search to the same element for every function you apply to it.